# How can I use Apple screen sharing in full screen mode?

Tags: screen-sharing

I've tried everything but I can only get Apple screen sharing to work in a window on its own.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Screen Sharing.app supports full-screen display, but you can use another VNC client.  The go-to client for Mac OS X is [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/), which is featureful and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen is correct.  Screen Sharing doesn't support full screen, but Apple Remote Desktop does support full screen...  (The ARD application that is...)

So if you have a large number of systems you are trying to remotely manage, ARD might be a good investment.  Otherwise, other applications (VNC), can and do support full screen sharing...